# Jquery can not animate backgroundColor property

Tags: jquery-plugins

I get the error message **"Error: 'start.0' is null or not an object"**
while animating backgroundColor property of an element.

I included the color plugin and able to animate borderTopColor,color etc.

Html part:

`<div id="divAnimation" style="">
        hello
</div>`

Javascript Part:
 `$("#divAnimation").animate({
            color: "red",

            backgroundColor:"#123456",  

            borderTopColor:"black",

            borderLeftColor:"green",

            borderRightColor:"silver",

            borderBottomColor:"yellow"
            },
               "slow");`

When i remove **backgroundColor:"#123456",**  there is no problem.

Any idea?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you'll need a plugin.  I suggest: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

Comment: hi again i used it indeed, i can animate border colors but having problem with backgroundColor. here a link for the above page if you are interested in with this also.but it is not important i guess you have other things to do. 
http://clients.entegral.com.tr/test/treeview.htm

Comment: @mehmet6parmak - You need to give `#divAnimation` a default background color to fix this, it can't animate from transparent, something like `<div id="divAnimation" style="background-color: White;">`

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem when trying to animate the backgroundColor of a div.

I was getting the same error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'start.0' is null or not an object

But this only happened in Internet Explorer (IE8). The animation worked fine in Chrome 10 and Firefox 4.

Eventually I traced the problem to using a colour **name** to specify the initial background colour of the div.

```
style="background-color: chocolate"
```

I changed to using **RGB values** to specify the initial colour:

```
style="background-color: rgb(128, 0, 0)"
```

This solved the problem.

Additional information: Using jquery-1.5.1 and jquery-ui-1.8.11.

Comment: This worked for me and it was nice not to require another plugin.